# Changing the Page Layout (for all pages)

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles, page-numbering

I want to add the chapter name at location (x,y) with center alignment , so the page number and the date. But what is wrong with the code? If I get this,How can I add date (for every chapter) and move it the location (x,y)?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\backgroundsetup{
angle=0,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
color=black,
contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=center,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north west) + (16.3cm,-1.8cm)$) {\thepage};
\node[anchor=center,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) + (20cm,-5cm)$) {\thechapter};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
}


%\usepackage[step=0.5cm,arrows=false,firstcolor=white,secondcolor=white]{pagegrid}    %% comment this
%\pagegridsetup{top-left}      %% comment this

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}   %% this is needed
\chapter*{Hello World}
\lipsum[4-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are the exact coordinates where you want your chapter with north west as the origin?

Comment: My chapter title should appear in the sheet at (15,2.7), the chapter number at (3.8,2.7) and the date of the chapter at (16.5,2.7) with the existing page number settings. All coordinates are in cm @HarishKumar

Comment: 1st box (exp.no) - height 1.5cm and width 2.8cm

Comment: 2nd box (title) - height 1.5cm and width 11.1cm

Comment: 3rd box date - height 1.5cm and 3.8cm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put all things inside a `tikzpicture` without using `\chapter*{..}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\backgroundsetup{
angle=0,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
color=black,
contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=center,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north west) + (16.3cm,-1.8cm)$) {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
}


%\usepackage[step=0.5cm,arrows=false,firstcolor=white,secondcolor=white]{pagegrid}    %% comment this
%\pagegridsetup{top-left}      %% comment this

\begin{document}
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}   %% do this at the start of each expt
\pagestyle{empty}   %% this is needed
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=center,inner sep=0pt,font=\Large\bfseries] at ($(current page.north west) + (3.8cm,-2.7cm)$) {Expt \thechapter};
\node[anchor=center,inner sep=0pt,font=\Large\bfseries] at ($(current page.north) + (0cm,-2.7cm)$) {Hello World};
\node[anchor=center,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north west) + (16.5cm,-2.7cm)$) {5.04.2014};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\lipsum[4-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]